# Change background colour of ul li

Tags: css

I struggle with the problem, that I want to change the background colour of my ul item, when the li is clicked.
So, I open a dropdown menu, click on the li link, and now I want that the mainmenuslot changes its backgroundcolor.

I am working with this code:

```
#mainnav-menu ul li.current_page_item a, #mainnav-menu ul li.current-menu-item a {
    background-color: #004494;
    background: #004494;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

What do I have to add, to get this function? I tried it with #mainnav-menu ul a, #mainnav-menu ul, and a lot of other possibilities.

Comment: Fiddle please??

Comment: Some relevant HTML code may help!?

Comment: please give us fiddle link or snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @jacobdo said, you only have the possibility to access li focus and to change li background, color (as explained below) and so on, but you won't have the possibility to change ul background, color without javascript.

```css
li:focus  {
  outline: 0;
   background-color: #004494;
    background: #004494;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="menus">
    <ul>
        <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">My Page</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Other Page</a></li>
        <li tabindex="0" style="border-right:none;"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/8zzc3oow/

With javascipt only:

http://jsfiddle.net/2jpehad9/

Of course jQuery and javascript change color events must be fulfilled when user clicks on the li link.

jQuery click - https://api.jquery.com/click

jQuery click example

```
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

js click example

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()" onclick="alert('clicked')">

<script>
// On mouse-over, execute myFunction
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").click(); // Click on the checkbox
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: To explain that he cannot get to ul parent without javascript cause he can only access li's css and to explain how he can get click and change color "events" with js and with jQuery. What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select parent of a child element via css (ul that has the li in it, in your case).

Here the easiest would be to change the background of your ul via javascript.